# Python prints two lines in the same line when merging files

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I'm getting this result and I am not sure how to fix it efficiently.

I have n files, let's say for simplicity just two, with some info with this format:

1.250484649 4.00E-02

2.173737246 4.06E-02

... ...

This continues up to m lines. I'm trying to append all the m lines from the n files in a single file. I prepared this code:

```
import glob


outfile=open('temp.txt', 'w')
for inputs in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    infile=open(inputs,'r')
    for row in infile:
        outfile.write(row)
```

It reads all the .dat files (the ones I am interested in) and it does what I want but it merges the last line of the first file and the first line of the second file into a single line:

1.250484649 4.00E-02

2.173737246 4.06E-02

3.270379524 2.94E-02

3.319202217 6.56E-02

4.228424345 8.91E-03

4.335169497 1.81E-02

4.557886098 6.51E-02

5.111075901 1.50E-02

5.547288248 3.34E-02

5.685118615 3.22E-03

5.923718239 2.86E-02

6.30299944 8.05E-03

**6.528018125 1.25E-020.704223685 4.98E-03**

1.961058114 3.07E-03

... ...

I'd like to fix this in a smart way. I can fix this if I introduce a blank line between each data line and then at the end remove all the blank likes but this seems suboptimal.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no newline on the last line of each `.dat` file, so you'll need to add it:

```py
import glob

with open('temp.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for inputs in glob.glob('*.dat'):
        with open(inputs, 'r') as infile:
            for row in infile:
                if not row.endswith("\n"):
                    row = f"{row}\n"
                outfile.write(row)
```

Also using `with` (context managers) to automatically close the files afterwards.

---

To avoid a trailing newline - there's a few ways to do this, but the simplest one that comes to mind is to load all the input data into memory as individual lines, then write it out in one go using `"\n".join(lines)`. This puts `"\n"` between each line but not at the end of the last line in the file.

```py
import glob

lines = []
for inputs in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    with open(inputs, 'r') as infile:
        lines += [line.rstrip('\n') for line in infile.readlines()]

with open('temp.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

`[line.rstrip('\n') for line in infile.readlines()]` - this is a list comprehension. It makes a list of each line in an individual input file, with the `'\n'` removed from the end of the line. It can then be `+=` appended to the overall list of lines.

While we're here - let's use `logging` to give status updates:

```py
import glob
import logging

OUT_FILENAME = 'test.txt'

lines = []
for inputs in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    logging.info(f'Opening {inputs} to read...')
    with open(inputs, 'r') as infile:
        lines += [line.rstrip('\n') for line in infile.readlines()]
    logging.info(f'Finished reading {inputs}')


logging.info(f'Opening {OUT_FILENAME} to write...')
with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n'.join(lines))
logging.info(f'Finished writing {OUT_FILENAME}')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works as I want! But at the end of the 'temp.txt' now I there is a blank line. Won't that be problematic if I try to read this data later on?

Comment: It might, it might not - I've edited to include a (possibly naive) approach which avoids the trailing newline.

Comment: This is what I wanted, thank you! :)